# Import .dat file into 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

I need to import a .dat file into a 2d array, there are 15 lines of text in the file before the data begins, separated by a space. Once imported i have to plot an eliminate noise from the data, however, i can't seem to get the data to import properly.

This is my attempt

```
 import numpy as np
 data = np.array 

 def ProcessData(data):

    data = np.loadtxt("myfile.dat", delimiter = " ", skiprows = 15)
    print data

 ProcessData(data)

 >>>ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 10.0   0.0
```

10.0 and 0.0 are the first two values for each column of data. 
Can anyone point out what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `delimiter = " "`.  Use the default, `delimiter=None`.  Then any block of whitespace is treat as a separator of the data fields.

When you use `delimiter=" "`, then *each* space is significant, so a line such as `"1   2"` contains the fields `'1'`, `''`, `''`, `'2'`.  When you use `delimiter=None`, those three spaces are treated as a single separator.

In your case, I suspect the fields in your file are separated by tabs, not spaces.  A tab is also whitespace, so it will be treated as a separator when you use `delimiter=None`.